# If I have a df with many datetimes, and a timeseries of every three hours, how do I group the items of the df into the timeseries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have this timeseries

`timeSeries = pd.date_range("2021-05-18", "2022-05-19", freq="3H").strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

I have a df with a shape of [49472 rows x 14 columns], here is an example of the index which is the date and one column

```
                        ID             
Date
2021-05-18 23:49:02 nfq2mv
2021-05-18 20:44:08 nflpfg
2021-05-18 17:43:59 nfh2xn
2021-05-18 15:39:09 nfdw96
```

I want to group the df items into the timeseries time that is closest ahead of the Date. For example, the first item in the example, `2021-05-18 23:49:02 nfq2mv`, I want to go into the item of the timeseries, `2021-05-18 24:00:00`
How can I group these IDs into their respective timeseries item.

Comment: Please check if [`Timestamp.ceil()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.ceil.html) helps you to round the timestamps in the correct way. Hope `ts.ceil(freq='3H')` is doing the wanted change.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like exactly what I am looking for, but I am having a tough time with the format. Before converting the date to the index I tried ```for i in RedditDf.index:    RedditDf['Date'][i].ceil(freq='3H')``` but got AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ceil' Then I tried it with the date as the index using ```for i in RedditDf.index:
    RedditDf.index[i].ceil(freq='3H')``` and got IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Make sure the index is actually datetime: `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`. Then you can do `df.index.ceil("3H")`.

Comment: When i try to convert it to datetime, i get this error: dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: Date. When I created the date column initially I used ```datetime.utcfromtimestamp(submission.created_utc)``` so it should already be in datetime.